# Android N Multi-Window and AdView

Tags: android, admob, adview, multi-window, android-7.0-nougat

How are we supposed to show Admob ads in the Multi-Window feature introduced in Android N? The ads are logging that there isn't enough space to show the ad.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try using SmartBanner type of adMob?

Comment: @ChrisK. Yes, I always use `SMART_BANNER`.

Comment: In a couple of relative questions point that fixed dimensions are required. I.e. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26597854/2104724. This stands for tablets that support multi window screens, but I guess that this will happen in N too.

Comment: @ChrisK. Am I allowed to make the AdView smaller? I don't think that really is a good idea... I don't want to get banned because of some reason.

Comment: This is a good point for sure. I'm sorry I can't help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was fixed in one of the latest updates. The ads now appear for me when in multi-window.